Explaining how 3D surfaces relate to hyperbolic surface codes in a simple/intuitive way?
This paper says:

In principle one can obtain a CSS surface code by gluing polygons together
at their edges to form a surface.

This presentation shows:



Can you explain for a layman or at least non-quantum/error-code expert (someone with some basic Abstract Algebra-level math skills), how you go from one to the other? What is the relationship between the surface and the hyperbolic Poincaré disk? How do you relate the two exactly?
That is pretty cool that they are related though! That's all I know though, not how they are related in an intuitive way.
Partially what I have in mind that I'm wondering about, too, is, does this mean infinity (i.e. the hyperbolic Poincaré disk) can be represented using a finite surface?!?!
Please break down each complex mathematical term you end up using in the explanation. For example, the first paper says:

One puts qubits on the edges of these polygons and
associates Z-checks with each polygon face, acting on the edges of the polygon. One
associates an X-check with each vertex where some polygons meet such that the X-check
acts on all edges emanating from the vertex.

But what is a Z-check, X-check, etc.. Hard to follow what they are saying without having a ton of prereqs.

Please do not create new tags without first running them by the community.  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/37292/

"does this mean infinity (i.e. the hyperbolic Poincaré disk) can be represented using a finite surface?!?!" is a meaningless question/statement. What the authors/you probably have in mind that the universal cover of a compact (in your language, "finite") hyperbolic surface is noncompact (in your language, "infinity"), namely, the hyperbolic plane. The infinite tiling of the hyperbolic plane is completely determined by a finite data associated with a single fundamental polygon.
